# Use svg as map using leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

Is it possible to use SVG image as the base map for leaflet.js ?

In my case I have huge svg file and I wish to allow my users to use all of leaflet's features such as zoom, markers, layers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can just use [imageOverlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay), like this

```js
// create the map
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [40.75, -74.2],
  zoom: 13
});

var imageUrl = 'https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/svg/australiaHigh.svg',
  imageBounds = [
    [40.712216, -74.22655],
    [40.773941, -74.12544]
  ];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! How did you calculate the bounds ?

Comment: I updated the fiddle. It's up to you, could just do `imageBounds = [[0, 0], [100, 100]];` and then just pass `center: [50, 50], zoom: 1` to leaflet to keep it simple.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance (and thanks for your great answer) but what does setting the bounds and then passing center and zoom like the above comment do?

Comment: It seems that adding `crs: L.CRS.Simple` lets you specify things in pixels instead of lat/long.

Comment: I'm using leaflet in Android and showing image on webview. I'm loading the image from local cache. I'm not using remote URL as an `imageUrl`. In my case, `imageUrl` contain the location of local cache. For `.svg` it won't work

Comment: @Papan Just get the `height/width` coordinates from svg with this method - `getBBox()`

Comment: If you are having difficulties with the zoom, I recommend to export as PNG and use then the same way as an image overlay, it will work like a charm, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/Lfzrqvet/

Answer (score 0):

### Translate SVG to leaflet coordinates

In addition to [**Rob Imig's** answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897704/use-svg-as-map-using-leaflet-js#34904736)
you probably want to place markers relative to your svg coordinates.

Based on the official [leaflet simple CRS example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple-example1.html):

1. check your SVG's intrinsic width/height or `viewBox` values
2. apply these values to the bounds like so:

```js
const bounds = [[0, 0], [svgHeight, svgWidth]];
```

So we need to swap x/y order as explained by
[IvanSanchez ("Leaflet+GeoJSON: Why are lat-lng coordinates in the wrong order?")](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244651/leafletgeojson-why-are-lat-lng-coordinates-in-the-wrong-order)

> Leaflet uses lat-lng (or northing-easting)

```js
const map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  minZoom: -2,
  maxZoom: 20
});

const bounds = [
  [0, 0],
  [607, 756]
];
const image = L.imageOverlay('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Mayor_of_London_constituency_results_2000.svg', bounds).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([303.5, 378]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup. SVG coordinates: x: 378; y:303.5").openPopup();


map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.leaflet-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 756/607;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

In the above example the intrinsic dimensions are:
**width:** 756
**height:** 607

We can place a marker at the horizontal and vertical center like so:

```
var marker = L.marker([ svgHeight/2, svgWidth/2]).addTo(map);
```

Play around with [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/bGQWYYq)