# how to add flyto leaflet function to Custom Svg Map

Tags: javascript, html, svg, leaflet

I have added a custom map svg leaflet
[Use svg as map using leaflet.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897704/use-svg-as-map-using-leaflet-js)

and given id to path (svg) and now I want to add flyto (leaflet function) to it. any idea how to do that. I am tring to animate flyto one path to another using leaflet

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [40.75, -74.2],
  zoom: 13
});
```

```
  imageBounds = [
    [40.712216, -74.22655],
    [40.773941, -74.12544]
  ];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

```
#map {
 height: 400px;
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

for flyto with animation you should use this code.

> map.panTo(new L.LatLng(40.712216,-74.22655));