# Leaflet SVG map showing new paths on zoom level

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I drew a simplified svg map of Europe and now I want to add "layers" to it. Like if you click on Spain, it will zoom in on it, change the fill color of the path and reveal before hidden subnational borders (I also have drawn paths for these already), which are clickable again and show a pop-up with some image and text on click. I thought about using leaflet for this and using the svg as the base map, it's easy to zoom, change color and open pop-ups on click, but I have no idea how I would "reveal" new paths.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share some code please?

Comment: I have yet to write code, I only have a few svg paths.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7VqqU12m

Here is an example of what I'm working with. A few countrie shapes as seperate paths, and only yet one path for a "subnational border" (which should be hidden until the country is clicked.)

Comment: Maybe this will get you started? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897704/use-svg-as-map-using-leaflet-js

Comment: Thanks! I found this thread, already. I guess, I just start coding and then ask again if I run into problems, I can't solve myself.